# Сервис генерация ссылки на получение денежного перевода

Tags: api

Есть ли сервисы/api платежных систем или банков, которые позволяют генерировать ссылки, которые можно отправить пользователю, который в удобное ему время сможет по этой ссылке получить с моего счета денежный перевод? Пишу бота для телеграм, у которого есть cashback за покупки. Хотелось это реализовать путем предоставления покупателю такой ссылки, чтобы не запрашивать у него доступ информацию для перевода денег (номер телефона и другие реквизиты).

Comment: Мне кажется, такие ссылки были бы "дырой" в безопасности счета, когда кто то может подобрать ссылку для снятия средств.